# how to take value from input and pass it to a object of plugin used in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, circliful

I have used a plugin to make a percentage loader circle.
 following is the js used after initializing that plugin:

```
$("#test-circle").circliful({
                animation: 1,
                animationStep: 5,
                foregroundBorderWidth: 15,
                backgroundBorderWidth: 15,
                percent: 35,
                textSize: 28,
                textStyle: 'font-size: 12px;',
                textColor: '#666',
                multiPercentage: 1,
                percentages: [10, 20, 30]
            });
```

I want the user to change the value of percent. For this i have used:

```
$("#submit").click(function(){
                var deg = ("#input").val();
                var degree = deg;
            });
```

Now I have the value from user , but i don't know how to pass it to plugin.
I am very new to jquery, and having a some trouble in doing this,

Comment: Try taking the entire `circliful` function and drop it into your click event, then change `percent: degree,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override some options of `circliful` in your click handler:

```
  var options = {  
    percent: 39
  };
  $("#test-circle").circliful(options);

  $('#submit').on('click', function() {
    var deg = $('#input').val();
    options.percent = deg;
    $("#test-circle").find('svg').remove();
    $("#test-circle").circliful(options);
  });
```

---

**[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Les0c5cw/3/)**

P.S.: You are using the ID `submit` in you click handler, if this element is a submit button and you are submitting a form, you have to work around the reload triggered by the form submit. Either use `e.prevenDefault` in the click handler and submit the form e.g. via `ajax` or save the percentage and apply it after form submit. If this applies to you of course.

Comment: thnx, this works fine. But just one is problem is there, everytime I click , it makes a duplicate circle

Comment: Everytime you click submit button you can remove the previous one before drawing i guess. You can do something like $('#test-circle').remove() before circle.circliful({percent:deg});